# Chevy Cruze Ltz 1.4

Tags: chevrolet, no-crank-no-start

i change starter and alternator and battery on chevy Cruze 2011 ltz and still no start ? What could be the problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is going on? What you've given us is basically nothing more than it won't crank or start. Do you turn the key (or press the button) and nothing happens? Do the dash lights light up? Do you hear *anything* when you try to start it? What's going on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.